# libertinus-otf does not print straight quotes in verbatim environment

Tags: fonts, typewriter, libertinus

Consider the following LuaLaTeX document:

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertinus-otf}
\setmonofont{CascadiaCod3-Light.otf} % from cascadia-code package on CTAN

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
  set(test "Test")
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Its output is

[image: curly quotes]

As can be seen there are curly quotes instead of straight quotes. The same would happen if one would not change the mono font, i.e. with Libertinus Mono. But there are straight quotes if one replaces `\usepackage{libertinus-otf}` by `\usepackage{fontspec}`.

Question: What does `libertinus-otf` change so that even other fonts' quotes are affected and how do I get straight quotes in mono fonts again?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I do not really know why or where the package modifies defaults (an educational answer on that is still welcome) but it seems it enables `Ligatures=TeX` even for the mono font. Using the `mono=false` option of the package does not have any effect.

However, disabling the TeX ligatures on the mono font that is loaded later on helps out and even keeps coding ligatures intact.

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertinus-otf}
\setmonofont{CascadiaCod3-Light.otf}[Ligatures = TeXOff]

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
"Test"

Coding ligatures: ^= 1 != 0
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image: ligatures]

Comment: make a bug report, the package should restrict the default font features to rmfamily and sffamily.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the suggestion but the package does not have an issue tracker as it seems and the author, Herbert Voß, did not mention any contact email address in the documentation or CTAN page either. It seems that there is no desire for bugs to be reported.

Comment: The mail address is in the sty and I never had a problem to reach Herbert and get an answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, thanks. Wouldn't have looked there for a mail address. I'll write him.

Comment: For a long time it was quite common to put addresses (and sometimes even the documentation) into the sty.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[defaultfeatures={Ligatures=TeXOff}]{libertinus-otf}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
"Test"

Coding ligatures: ^= 1 != 0
\end{verbatim}

\setmonofont{CascadiaCod3-Light.otf}
\begin{verbatim}
"Test"

Coding ligatures: ^= 1 != 0
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. Just to confirm: This does also turn off the TeX ligatures for the roman and sans font, right?

Comment: Right! I'll upload a new version of `libertines-off` which presets font features only to   roman and sans serif.